# substraction of groups in direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-sum

Assume I have a sub group $G\leq \mathbb Z^n$ and I have $\mathbb Z^n = G\oplus \mathbb Z^m $ for some $m\leq n$.

I want to deduce $G\cong\mathbb Z^{n-m}$. Is that true? how can I do it?

Comment: It is true and there are several ways to go about it. What have you tried/how much do you know about these objects?

Comment: i tried writing down an explicit isomorphism $G\to \mathbb Z^{n-m}$ using the original isomorphism, but it didnt work. 

You may assume I have decent knowledge in group theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ is a subgroup of a finitely generated abelian group. So itself must be also finitely generated. $G$ cannot contain any non-zero torsion as $\mathbb{Z}^n$ doesn't either. So $G\cong \mathbb{Z}^k$ where $k$ is a non negative integer. $\mathbb{Z}^k\oplus \mathbb{Z}^m \cong \mathbb{Z}^{m+k}$ so it follows.